# cant select object in LAYOUT

Tags: modeling, objects

this is happen coz after using sculupting,, then i cant select object what i want it...

but if im in tab Modelling and sculputing this is work...
[image: TAB Layout]

[image: tab Modelling]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have overlays turned off. You can turn them back on in the top right corner of the viewport, next to the Viewport Shading menu. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks bro this is helpfull,, i find about overlays around 15 minutes and got it...